# Document.ready not firing when contents are loaded with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drag-and-drop, document-ready

I am trying to implement a drag and drop module I have 3 files uploaded on server Display.php,t2.php and update.php:

t2.php is same as http://www.script.iblogger.org/ the drag and drop works perfectly fine here, but when I load the contents of t2.php in display.php (http://www.script.iblogger.org/display.php) via ajax call the document.ready function wouldn't fire, any help would greatly be appreciated.
Thank you in advance!
**EDIT:** How should I modify this?

**AJAX CALL FUNCTION IN display.php:**

```
    function showSubjects(str)
    {
    if (str=="")
      {
      document.getElementById("teacher-row").innerHTML="";
      return;
      } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("teacher-row").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","t2.php?s="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    }
```

**DOCUMENT READY FUNCTION IN t2.php:** (as document ready doesn't work via ajax call)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){...});
```

Comment: Are you connected to your database? And possibility to show some code?

Comment: you are having some db issues

Comment: I think it was technical error you are talking about not my code error, please check now its fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is little mistake, document.ready is fire when page load.

so resolve this issue perform your operation when ajax request response back:

> success:function(response){ your code here... }

Answer (score 1):

The [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) does not fire when contents are loaded by ajax, you need to use `success`, `complete`, `done` etc event. You can read more over about ajax events [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

#### document.ready

> JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a page is
>   rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets such as
>   images have been completely received. In most cases, the script can be
>   run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed. The
>   handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM
>   is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event
>   handlers and run other jQuery code. When using scripts that rely on
>   the value of CSS style properties, it's important to reference
>   external stylesheets or embed style elements before referencing the
>   scripts, [reference](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: It means document.ready is fired when page is loaded amd DOM is ready. It is not fired when ajax call is completed